# How to search Mac OS X Mail by List-Id?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I would really like to search based off the header `List-Id` but I haven't found a way to do this yet.

When I type `List-Id: <blah@group.company.com>` into search, I get no results

Comment: What "List-Id", I can not find that in Mac mail.

Comment: If you hit **Control + Shift + H** to see full headers. If the email is a email following the list-id secification for email, then you will see something like this `List-Id: <blah@group.company.com>`. Read this for example http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2011/10/27/list-id-for-filtering-mail/